# Determine the audio format of an audio file stored in bytearray and play it

Tags: java, audio, encryption

I have encrypted an audio file (.wav, .midi, .au, .mid) and want to decrypt it and play the audio without storing it to disk. I have a bytearray after decrypting the audio file, and now I have to play it.

My problem is how to **find the audio format** from this resulted bytearray and **play it**.

```
byteoutput=new byte[(int) fileSize];
```

Comment: Well, first you'd start by Googling the likely formats and finding out what their headers look like.  Then write the code to differentiate between them.  Finally, find or write the code to play those formats you wish to handle.  (Of course, you're not going to find out much about "byteoutput" until you read some data into it.)

Comment: Can't you just store the audio file type along with the byte array?  I'm assuming you knew the type when you first encrypted it?

Comment: @pace yes,but when converting a audio file to bytearray,does the byte array itself won't have its audio format specification in it?